# How to specify Many to Many relationship with different microservices in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, microservices, associations

I'm implementing different microservices in Node JS. I came up with some complex scenario. Let me try to explain the issue below.

There are 2 microservices:

1. User
2. System

I need to specify many to many relationship between User and System. The problem is User model is in different microservice, while the System model is in some other microservice.
So, is there some way we can specify Many-to-Many relationship with User and System using Sequelize for PostgreSQL and Node JS.
Can we somehow make these associations using table references instead of models? Or is there some other way to achieve the above discussed functionality?

Your response will be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking if you can create an association between tables that are in two separate databases?

Comment: What info you need in each microservice from the other one?

Comment: I need to access the reference to their models/tables, so that I can specify associations between them. And in our scenario, database is same for all the microservices.

Comment: Why are you implementing microservices?  Because if you're using the same database and defining associations in that database that cross microservices, you're better off with a monolith (because attempting to do microservices in that scenario will give you all the headaches of both the monolith and microservices for little or no actual gain)